# Start GPS navigation application from code

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, gps

I'm building a Windows Mobile 6.1 application using .NET and C#.

I would like to purchase a GPS Navigation application or control so that I can add navigation functionality to my application. My software displays a list of customers. I would like users to be able to click an address and then navigate to this location using "turn by turn" navigation (similar to Tom Tom or Navman etc).

It's very time-consuming downloading demos and evaluating all the options. Has anyone been through this process and found a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting time stuffing around with Google, Bing and others I came across these guys. Really excellent product! Send the address to their app and you're done. Simple :)

http://www.sygic.com/en/business